# Application is not deployed with argocd

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, argocd

An external cluster was registered using the argocd API.
And I tried to deploy the application to the cluster, but an error occurred.
I can't find the cause of the error.

```
@Getter @Setter
public class ArgocdClusterTlsClientConfigRequest extends BaseArgocdClusterRequest{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1346256037019682884L;
    private boolean insecure;
    private String certData;
}
```

```
@Getter @Setter
public class ArgocdClusterConfigRequest extends BaseArgocdClusterRequest{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4651475696074700873L;
    private String bearerToken;
    private ArgocdClusterTlsClientConfigRequest tlsClientConfig;
}
```

```
@Getter @Setter
public class ArgocdClusterRgstRequest extends BaseArgocdClusterRequest{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5302969394560219121L;
    
    private ArgocdClusterConfigRequest config;
    private String name;
    private String server;
}
```

Using the three objects above, the necessary data was loaded into the payload and requested as a resttemplate.

I created three resources in the cluster I wanted to register, and put the result of decoding the secret value into base64 in the token

The certData of ArgocdClusterTlsClientConfigRequest contains the client-certificate-data of $HOME/.kube/config.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: argocd-controller-sa
  namespace: kube-system
  uid: dd39f1b9-8dfc-4378-ae92-70a7c0331377
secrets:
- name: argocd-controller-sa-token-ncsfz
```

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: argocd-controller-role
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - '*'
  resources:
  - '*'
  verbs:
  - delete
  - get
  - patch
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - events
  verbs:
  - list
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - pods
  - pods/log
  verbs:
  - get
- apiGroups:
  - argoproj.io
  resources:
  - applications
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
```

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: argocd-controller-rolebinding
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: argocd-controller-role
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: argocd-controller-sa
  namespace: kube-system
```

However, argocd continues to return an error.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/saFbR.png